# unittest in Python Flask: Print messages are truncate

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm writing my first ever Flask tests using unittest. At the moment I have three simple tests, something like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    app = create_app()
    self.app = app.test_client()

def test_1(self):
    response = self.app.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

def test_2(self):
    response = self.app.get('/endpoint1', follow_redirects=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

def test_3(self):
    headers = { "API-KEY": "myKey", "Accept": "application/xml" 
    response = self.app.get('/endpoint1', follow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

While debugging the last test, I noticed that most of its print statements are never seems to make it to my console. I know that it hits the place in my code that return a 403, but the print statements leading up to that return statement seems to somehow be truncated.

The print statements from the two first tests are all output to my console.

Even if I change the ordering of the tests, the print statements from the last one always seems to be truncated.

May it be that when the final test runs, the unittest framework tear down the server before the server get the chance to finalize outputting its (buffered?) print statements to the console?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like using the "with" block, as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#test-client) does the trick.

Example:

```
def test_3(self):
    with self.app:
       headers = { "API-KEY": "myKey", "Accept": "application/xml" 
       response = self.app.get('/endpoint1', follow_redirects=True,    headers=headers)          
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```